# Rescaling axes without zooming

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, scaletransform

I'd like to rescale the axis of a MATLAB plot without modifying the underlying data. I'm *not* trying to zoom in on a particular region of the plot.

As an example, lets say I have my X axis in millimetres. My American colleagues might prefer to see the output in inches, but everything is coded in millimetres, and it'd be a hell of a job to create new inch-based data for all the items I'd like to plot. Ideally, I'd just plot everything as usual, and in a couple of lines of code, have the X-axis adjust to inches at the end.

How do I do this?

Basic code to get things started:

```
plot([1:2:100], [1:50])
xlabel('Millimetres')
ylabel('Something else')

% Magic happens

xlabel('Inches')
```

Note: 1 inch is 25.4 millimetres.

Answer (score 1):

First, what's the problem dividing your x-data by 25.4 ?

```
x=[1:2:100]; y=[1:50];
plot(x/25.4,y)
```

will do. This will also automatically place the X-Ticks positions and Labels in a nice round number positions.

If you insist, this will convert the current X-Tick Labels from mm to inch units:

```
xt     = get(gca, 'XTick');
xlabels= get(gca, 'XTickLabel');
set(gca, 'XTick', xt, 'XTickLabel',num2str(str2num(xlabels)/25.4) );
```

Comment: Perfect. The reason for not rescaling the data themselves is that in my real program, I'm plotting many things on the same axes.

Comment: One little thing: This solution removes the ability to zoom in on the plot and have MATLAB generate new tick-marks. Essentially, I only have one zoom level. Is there a way to get MATLAB to do this for all zoom levels?

Comment: rescale your x-axis (my first option) will do it.